# Probability of candies

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I need some help with my solution review.

I have next problem from my class:

"There are three candies and two systems to distribute them: system 1 contains two boys and system 2 contains three girls.  Every boy and girl with an equal probability can have zero, one, two, or three candies. Kids are distinguishable, but candies aren't. What is the most probable number of candies in the system 1? What is the average number of candies in the system 1?"

My solution:
The final candies distribution can be described by the sequence of length 5, consisting from 0 to 3 numbers and with the total sum of enters = 3.

Let’s guess that all candies must be distributed and the sequences of the form 00000 etc. are impossible. So we have

$C_5^1 + C_5^1 * C_4^2 + C_5^3 = 5 + 5*6 + 10 = 45$

$C_n^k := \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

| $C_5^1$ | $C_5^1*C_4^2$ | $C_5^3$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [30][000] | [12][000] | [11][100] |
| [03][000] | [10][200] | [10][101] |
| [00][300] | ... | ... |
| [00][030] | ... | ... |
| [00][003] | [20][001] | [00][111] |

The most probable number of the system 1. Number of system 1 positions for $C_5^1$: 10, for $C_5^1*C_4^2$: 60, for $C_5^3$: 20. So we have a distribution of system 1 elements, the size of which = 90.

For $C_5^1$: 2 positions for 3 and 8 for 0
For $C_5^1*C_4^2$: 10 positions for 1, 10 positions for 2 and 40 positions for 0
For $C_5^3$: 12 positions for 1 and 8 for 0

$p(3) = \frac{2}{90} $
$p(2) = \frac{10}{90} $
$p(1) = \frac{22}{90} $
$p(0) = \frac{56}{90}$

=> The most probable number of the system 1 is 0.

$E($system 1$) = 3*\frac{1}{45} + 2*\frac{1}{9} + \frac{11}{45} = 0.53$ candies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive but logical guess for the expected number going to the boys would be $3 \times \frac25= \frac 65=1.2$ using linearity of expectation or exchangeability.

Most of your counts have errors and your $C_4^2$ should be $C_4^1$ - though I would prefer to write this as ${4 \choose 1}$ and similarly with the other combinations:

- Your "2 positions for 3 and 8 for 0" for $3+0+0+0+0$ should be $2$ cases of $3$ candies to the boys and $3$ cases of $0$ candies to the boys, adding to $5 = C_5^1$.
- Your "10 positions for 1, 10 positions for 2 and 40 positions for 0" for $2+1+0+0+0$ should be  $2$ cases of $3$ candies to the boys and  $6$ cases of $2$ candies to the boys and  $6$ cases of $1$ candy to the boys and  $6$ cases of $0$ candies to the boys, adding to $20=C_5^1\times C_4^1$.
- Your "12 positions for 1 and 8 for 0" for $1+1+1+0+0$ should be  $3$ cases of $2$ candies to the boys and  $6$ cases of $1$ candy to the boys and  $1$ case of $0$ candies to the boys, adding to $10=C_5^3$.

In total there are $35$ cases and if they are equally likely then the probabilities for the numbers of candies going to the boys are then $P(3)=\frac{4}{35}, P(2)=\frac{9}{35}, P(1)=\frac{12}{35}, P(0)=\frac{10}{35}$ and this also leads to the expected number of candies to the boys of $\frac{42}{35}=\frac65=1.2$

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was helpfull!